# C++ choose specific function returns

Tags: c++, function, visual-studio-2012

I have a simple (for you) question on C++ function programming. I am declaring the following function:

```
double Function (double x,
                     double y,
                     double z,
                     double k,
                     double u)
Do things...
double array[1];
return array[0]=value1;
return array[1]=value2;
```

Now on the `main(){}` I want to output both values. So, I go:

```
    double result[1] = {SimpleMonteCarlo(x,
                                  y,
                                  z,
                                  k,
                                  u)};
cout << "the first result is " << result[0] << "\n";
cout << "the second result is" << result[1] << "\n"
```

However, it looks like only `result[0]` (`array[0]`) has the correct value. If I set value2 to `array[0]` again no problem.

Any idea on how to go around it? And most importantly, why this happening?

Thanks a lot for the effort guys! :)

Comment: `double [1]` declares an array of one element. The only valid index into it is `[0]`. Note also that you cannot return a normal array from a function.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Angew. It looks like that is the only way to get atleast 1 correct unswer. If I change to `array[2]` and `result[2]` does not make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

returning an array which is created on stack as your above code is extremely dangerous and will most likely lead to data corruption. I suggest that you use an argument for returning your results like this:

```
void Function(double x, double y, double output[2])
{
     //Do your calculations
     output[0] = value0;
     output[1] = value1;
}
```

and you will call the function like this:

```
double retVal[2];
Function(x, y, retVal);
cout << retVal[0] << retVal[1];
```

Another way is to allocate an array on heap inside the function and return it; but in that case the caller has to deallocate the array (meaning extra programmer work and caution!). IMHO for a simple case like yours the first type of declaring function is better.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks a lot for your comments and time. Explanation is perfectly understood.

Comment: the other answer would be returning an std::vector, which for returning 2 doubles is a waste (specially if the function is in performance critical part of code)

Comment: I do believe that the array should be passed by reference.

Comment: @Kourosh [NRVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization). Don't encourage premature optimization, especially not the kind which sacrifices safety.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, **you can't return arrays from a function.** What you should generally use instead is an `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> SimpleMonteCarlo()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(42);
    vec.push_back(1337);
    return vec;
}

std::vector<int> vec = SimpleMonteCarlo();
std::cout << vec[0] << " " << vec[1] << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function, you are returning only one value.

```
double Function (double x,
                     double y,
                     double z,
                     double k,
                     double u) {
//do some stuff
double array[1];
return array[0]=value1;
return array[1]=value2; //this line is never executed... so it can be written in code, but has no effect. Its same as if it were comment out
}
```

There is no problem with inner array. Hovewer, your logic is incorrect. In your code

```
double result[1] = {SimpleMonteCarlo(x,
                                  y,
                                  z,
                                  k,
                                  u)};
cout << "the first result is " << result[0] << "\n";
cout << "the second result is" << result[1] << "\n"
```

You have problem with last line. You are trying to read value `result[1]`, that never exists. And having array only for 1 item is useless and bad design.